# How to hyerlink in a jquery function

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, onclick

I need to hide some buttons, show others then hyperlink to a new web page using a button's onclick event.

I have the hidden/visible code working in a jquery function but don't know (and have tried to find out) how to add the hyperlink call to the function.

Do I have to add a hidden button and use ".click" or is there a better way?

Comment: Code is worth a thousand words (as is markup). Yes, you'd use `click`, but no, you probably don't need to add a hidden button. Show your code for *useful* answers.

Comment: Read what you've just written too , the title of your question makes no sense : "How to hyerlink in a jquery function" what does that mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this function you've added on the onclick event, you want to redirect the user to another url? If I understood it right, what you'd want to use in your function is probably:

```
window.location.href = "http://thesite.com";
```